# Cursor query needs 2.5 seconds to return - Need a workaround

Tags: android

My Android application has two activities:

- `MainActivity` which contains a button to `MsgActivity`
- `MsgActivity` which contains a back button and one `TextView` per result from the following query:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");
Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri,  new String[] {}, "", new String[]{}, "date desc LIMIT 5");
```

It requires up to 2.5sec to complete, so to avoid waiting every time I launch the `MsgActivity`, I would like to:

1. Cache the result of the query / the cursor *OR*
2. Prevent the `MsgActivity` from being destroyed when I press the back button.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To 1: You shouldn't cache a `Cursor` directly, but caching the result should be no problem. The normal way to cache data is to write it to a file in the directory returned by `getCacheDir()`.

To 2: You can prevent an `Activity` from being destroyed on back press by overriding `onBackPressed()`. In this case you should start your `MainActivity` from there (with `FLAG_ACITVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)`. You should also call your `MsgActivity` always with this flag.

Alternatively to using said flag you can set your activities as singleInstance

```
<activity android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
```

Another solution would be an ahead of time query - Execute the query e.g. in an `AsyncTask` in your `MainActivity` and pass it to the `MsgActivity`

---

Edit to 1:
If you want to cache only for the lifecycle of your app, place the logic in

- `static` fields and methods (You may want to do this in a `final` class) OR
- A singleton object OR
- A class extending `Application`

Choose what suits you best, there is no best choice IMO.

Comment: 1) I think that I should keep it in volatile memory so that I can avoid file r/w delay...

Comment: 2) I tried to do so but the app does not want to listen to me, it keeps calling MsgActivity.onDestroy()...

Comment: 2) Be sure not to call `super.onBackPressed()`. Also Android will still kill the activity if it is low on memory.

Comment: Yep, I did try not calling the super method but I didn't work however

Comment: I think that the third solution you suggested me is the best one. I will implement this one. Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results to be in memory all the time, you could store them in a static object. It might not be the most elegant solution, but it should work.

Or if you want the results to last for several executions (probably not from what you write) you could put them in a SQLite database.

Comment: According to what I've understood about cursor and msg queries, it is saved in a sqlite db so, If I got what you mean, I think that the problem will remain the same.